# only one space, hyphen or apostrophe for this i used given code but it not working properly

Tags: regex

Name must be between 2 and 25 characters and can contain only one space, hyphen or apostrophe
for this i used given code but it not working properly.
    ^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z-\s']*$

Comment: Only one of each space, hyphen or apostrophe or only one of all three?

Comment: don't use regex for password validation, use separate functions for each constraint! When the constraints changes the update will be a breeze compared to going through a regex

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lookahead to detect that there is exactly zero or one such character in the expression:

```
/^(?=^[^\s'-]*[\s'-]?[^\s'-]*$)[a-zA-Z\s'-]{2,}$/
```

Comment: @FredrikPihl I wrote this to only allow one of any of the three rather than one of each.  In order to allow for one of each, you need to split up the lookaheads: http://rubular.com/r/Lr90Cio0sx

Comment: I see now, +1 for the extra effort!